# What's the name of this opening for white?

Tags: opening

[image]

What's the name of this structure after white castling ?

Comment: Could you explain the move order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally known as the Glek System. It looks like Nc3 and Nf6 were omitted.

One of White's general plans is to play d3 and Be3 hoping for the trade to open the f-file, and also to play Nf3-h4-f5. .

Answer (score -2):

i played black with this against an expert

he started with p-kn3
shredder says it is the benko opening 1)p-kn3

so whatever that move is called would be it
although it may have transposed to something else which would also be a proper name for it

that was one of my best wins
i sacked a rook for knight an a pawn in a semi-closed position and got an advantage in the center while his rooks were not doing much while my extra bishop guarded key squares

p-kn3    p-k4
b-n2     b-b4
p-k4     p-q3
0-0

not sure which order i played the knights
but that was essentially our opening position

Comment: Is there any relevant information here regarding the question asked? It just seems like boasting, to be honest.